# Dealing with messy JSON with R

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I have this json file [(this URL)](https://geodes.santepubliquefrance.fr/GC_indic.php?lang=fr&prodhash=ca0a67cc&indic=rea&dataset=covid_hospit&view=map2&filters=sexe=0,jour=2021-05-08)

When I exectute the following code :

```
url <- "the_url_mentioned_above.com"

df <- fromJSON(url)

new_dataframe <- as.data.frame(df)
```

I hit this error message :

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Comment: The returned JSON structure is not a data frame but a complex hierarchical of lists.  You will need to determine which part you need access to.  For example maybe just this `df$content$zonrefs$values[[1]]`

Comment: I didn't figured out that it was such a complex list. The path you've determined works fine. Very helpful, thanks